# Maintain a Single generated c# class for multiple versions of a XSD

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have two versions of xsd files.
Both are different versions of same schema.

There are minute differences between these two files. i.e Some nodes are same and others are different.

For ex: A complex type ABC has qwe, rty properties in one version
But in the second version ABC has qwe, mnp, zxc properties.

Also, there are other complex types which are completely same in both versions.

Now I do not want to generate two separate classes for these two schemas (xsd files) using xsd.exe tool.

Instead is there any option where only one c# class can be maintained for both versions of xsd files?

I have a field by field mapping of the xsd to other Objects. But since I had to generate two separate classes for two versions of xsd, the mapping code is getting duplicated.

So any clue or any new design pattern to fix this Versioning and avoiding duplicate mapping code. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You could build a class containing all the properties of the 2 XSD files and manualy serialize/deserialize it. You could then tag each property with a custom attribute specifying the version of it. Thanks to that you can know which properties are mandatory for deserialization and which are not.

Comment: can you elaborate on this. I did not get what you were saying.. Please gove an example

Comment: Well I realize that my answer is only relevant for the serialization/deserialization of some XML. If you wanted some advise on XSD.exe I cannot help you...